# Facing error as invalid literal for int () with base 10: in swift 2

Tags: ios, arrays, dictionary, swift2, uialertview

[image]

As per screenshot while am submitting the feedback facing this issue. Any help is appreciated.

I have to enter comments like smile or sad after that am typing some text about the ride. Everything was working fine. While I am clicking on submit button I am getting `journeyId` as `nil` other than that in `self.journeyAPIdetails` I am getting the whole data from JSON. Thanks in advance.

```
 func submitButtonTapped() {

            if self.smileActive! == true || self.frownActive!  == true {

                let comment = (self.mainView.textfield.text! == "Tap to Type" || self.mainView.textfield.text! == "Leave any additional Comments here") ? "": self.mainView.textfield.text!

                let rating = self.smileActive! == true ? "true":"false"

                let journeyId = self.journeyAPIdetails!["data"]["journey_id"].stringValue
                let userId = AccountService.sharedInstance.typeOfUser() == .Customer ? self.journeydetails?.driver.id : self.journeydetails?.customer.id


                let details = ["rating":rating, "comment":comment, "journey_id":journeyId]

                JourneyService().rateAUser(details).onSuccess { (json) -> Void in

                    if json["status"].stringValue == "success" {
                        print("dismissViewControllerAnimate")
                        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                        AccountService.sharedInstance.clearJourneyContent()

                     } else if json["status"].stringValue == "fail" {

                        print("dismissViewControllerAnimated")

                        self.displayAlert("Error", message: json["message"].stringValue)
                    }
                }
            }

            else {
                super.displayAlert("Feedback", message: "Give some feedback and optionally add some comments.")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The error message comes from Python (likely the JourneyService server), not Swift. Are you sure you provided the correct input to the `rateAUser()`?

Comment: it is related to python

Comment: yes, provided correct input for driver side am able to give customer's feedback.In case Customer's side only am facing issue.As per my understanding it's not python issue @kennytm,@Anbu.Karthik.

Comment: @Vinathynvr Could you show how `rateAUser` parse the `details` in the Python side? In particular the line running `int(something)`.

Comment: po details
▿ 3 elements
  ▿ [0] : 2 elements
    - .0 : "rating"
    - .1 : "true"
  ▿ [1] : 2 elements
    - .0 : "comment"
    - .1 : "eewwe"
  ▿ [2] : 2 elements
    - .0 : "journey_id"
    - .1 : ""

Comment: @kennytm am not getting journey_id is showing as nil.

Comment: @Vinathynvr Looks like you need to go back further and check whether `journeyAPIdetails` contains a valid journey_id.

Comment: @kennytm it has valid journey_id.Here is response "driver_started" : true,
      "journey_id" : "637",
      "customer_picked" : true,
      "reached_destination" : true,

Comment: @Vinathynvr Is it `journeyAPIdetails` or `journeyAPIdetails["data"]`?

Comment: @kennytm self.journeyAPIdetails!["data"]["journey_id"].stringValue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139263/discussion-between-kennytm-and-vinathy-nvr).

Answer (score 1):

`invalid literal for int () with base 10: ''` is the error message from Python indicating you want to convert an empty string to an integer. This means the server expects a string that contains decimal digits, but you give it an empty string instead. This points to `details` having wrong input, in particular the `journeyId` field.

After [discussing with OP](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/139263), we find out the problem is in `self.journeyAPIdetails!["data"]`: it is an array containing an single object, but OP didn't notice it. So the solution is to change that line to:

```
let journeyId = self.journeyAPIdetails!["data"][0]["journey_id"].stringValue
//                                             ^^^
```

Moral of the story: be careful to analyze the structure of the JSON you send and receive.